# Publishing local libraries to remote maven repository

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin

I have a set of libraries which I want to publish into our organization's remote `maven` repository. Right now I have created a local directory and put all the libraries there. 
I have specified this local directory as the repository using the below :

```xml
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>project-repo</id>
        <name>custom repo</name>
        <url>file://${project.baseUri}/../repository</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

I want to migrate all the libraries under this repo to our organization's central repo located at http://mvn.app.xyz.repo.com.

How do I achieve it? How can I copy the libraries from the "project-repo" to the central repo?

I'm using maven version 3.1-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the Maven Deploy Plugin: [`mvn deploy:deploy-file`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/usage.html).